# How to group a data frame while containing information about two rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Python and I hope someone can help me with this performance issue.
My data looks like:

```
                   TIMESTAMP   A
34   2050-09-08 03:00:00 EST   3.0
40   2050-09-08 07:00:00 EST   3.0
67   2050-09-08 17:00:00 EST   6.0
84   2050-09-08 23:00:00 EST   6.0
89   2050-09-09 01:00:00 EST  11.0
103  2050-09-09 07:00:00 EST  10.0
110  2050-09-09 11:00:00 EST  10.0
118  2050-09-09 15:00:00 EST  10.0
```

I want get the time intervals in which the values in column A are Steady (S), Increasing (I) or Decreasing (D).

At this moment, I use a for-loop to compare the rows and calculate the slope between these values. As long as the sign of the slope does not change for every iteration, the end timestamp of the interval gets updated. This results in intervals like Interval(begin, end, state). The result for the example above would be:

```
Interval(2050-09-08 03:00:00 EST, 2050-09-08 07:00:00 EST, S)
Interval(2050-09-08 07:00:00 EST, 2050-09-08 17:00:00 EST, I)
Interval(2050-09-08 17:00:00 EST, 2050-09-08 23:00:00 EST, S)
etc.
```

Since the dataset contains many rows and columns, I'm trying to find a way to code this more efficiently (without a for-loop).

```
data['slope'] = compute_slopes(data)
data['state'].apply(lambda x: get_state(x))
data["shift"] = data["state"].shift(1)
data["check"] = data["state"] != data["shift"]
data["group"] = data["check"].cumsum()
begin_group = data.groupby("group").first()
end_group = data.groupby("group").last()
result = pd.concat([begin_group, end_group])
result = result.sort_values('TIMESTAMP')

                def compute_slopes(data):
                    next_df = data.shift(-1)
                    return getSlope(pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S EST'), df['A'], pd.to_datetime(next_df['TIMESTAMP'], format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S EST'), next_df['A'])


                def get_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
                    return (y2 - y1) / ((x2 - x1).dt.total_seconds()/60)


                def get_state(slope):
                    if(slope < 0):
                        state = 'D'     #DECREASING
                    elif(slope == 0):
                        state = 'S'     #STEADY
                    else:
                        state = 'I'     #INCREASING

                    return state
```

The code above results in something like below, but grouping this data frame does not work since there is one state which belongs to two timestamps (state S belongs to 03:00:00 and 07:00:00).

```
     TIMESTAMP                  A     slope     state
34   2050-09-08 03:00:00 EST   3.0  0.000000     S
40   2050-09-08 07:00:00 EST   3.0  0.005000     I
67   2050-09-08 17:00:00 EST   6.0  0.000000     S
84   2050-09-08 23:00:00 EST   6.0  0.041667     I
89   2050-09-09 01:00:00 EST  11.0 -0.002778     D
103  2050-09-09 07:00:00 EST  10.0  0.000000     S
110  2050-09-09 11:00:00 EST  10.0  0.000000     S
118  2050-09-09 15:00:00 EST  10.0  0.000000     S
```

In some way, I want to group these states and get the begin- and end timestamp for each state and save it in an interval. Does anyone know a quicker way than just looping through the data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be helpful.  Use lots of `shift` and then use `groupby` + `agg`.

```
df.loc[df.A < df.A.shift(-1), 'State'] = 'I'
df.loc[df.A > df.A.shift(-1), 'State'] = 'D'
df.loc[df.A == df.A.shift(-1).ffill(), 'State'] = 'S'
df['StateGroup'] = (df.State != df.State.shift()).cumsum()
df['NextTIMESTAMP'] = df.TIMESTAMP.shift(-1).ffill()
df
```

[image]

```
aggs = dict(A=['mean', 'count', 'first', 'last'], State=['first'],
            TIMESTAMP={'Start': 'first'}, NextTIMESTAMP={'End': 'last'})
df.groupby('StateGroup').agg(aggs)
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely helpful, exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: I am having a three for one special:  df['State'] = np.where(df.A.pct_change() > 0, "I", np.where(df.A.pct_change() <0 , "D","S"))